# Multiple connection error when using node js and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following schema located in my `/routes/schema.js` file...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    name: String,
    last: String,
    year: Number,
    degree: String

});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = {
    User: User
}
```

In my `/routes/register.js` file I am storing some information using POST data...

```
var User = require('../routes/schema').User; 

exports.postRegister = function (req, res) {
    var u = new User({
        username: req.body.reg_username,
        password: req.body.reg_password,
        name: req.body.reg_name,
        last: req.body.reg_lastname,
        year: req.body.reg_year,
        degree: req.body.reg_degree
    });

    u.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            console.log("saved");
            res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

        }
    });
}
```

Everything gets saved fine in my Database. But now, this `register.js` file redirects the user back to `/routes/index.js` where the user must then sign in using some credentials stored in the database.

So in my `index.js` file I need to check if username and password exist together in a collection in my database, I tried the following...

```
var User = require('../routes/schema').User; 

exports.signin = function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.log_username,
        password: req.body.log_password
    }, function (err, docs) {
        if (docs.length) {
            console.log("name exists");
        }
        else {
            console.log("no exist");
        }
    });
};
```

I used the `findOne` function with the same Schema to check if username and password exist in a collection in the database, but it doesn't work properly. I seem to get a multiple connection error and I do not know how to avoid it.

When I try to login using some credentials already in the database, the console prints out `no exist` meaning the else statement in `exports.signin` is reached.

Comment: Can you post the error messages you're getting?

Comment: @Kairat one error message that I get is that `docs.length` because `docs cannot be null`

Comment: Did you check whether the document is actually in your database?

Comment: @Kairat Oh whoops, that is not the right error message. I tested it again with something that exists in the db and the error I got is `no exist` meaning it reached the else statement in `exports.signin`

Comment: In `exports.signin`, try printing out `req.body.log_username` and `req.body.log_password` before calling `findOne()` to see if they match what you expect.

Comment: @Kairat yes I did that and it matches what I expect, the problem must be with the `findOne()`

Comment: One last thing you can try to verify whether it's `findOne()` or not (although I don't think the problem is `findOne()`), is to try calling `findOne` in `exports.postRegister()` right after `console.log("saved");` and before `res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });`. Essentially, try getting the document right after saving it.

Comment: try it `docs.length !== 0 `

Comment: Also, use `docs != null` instead of `docs.length` to avoid errors when the returned document is null.

Comment: LOL. that worked. Wow, can you explain to me why `if(docs.length)` does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it `docs.length !== 0` this is check docs field is existed or empty.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `docs` will be `null` if the object is not found in the collection.

If the user enters wrong credentials, you will be calling `docs.length` on null object, which will cause an error. Use `docs != null` instead, to avoid calling `length` on `null` object.